# Trouble Installing MySQL workbench

Tags: 11.10, dpkg, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to Ubuntu Linux. My Professor asked us to download Ubuntu 10.10. I have made several attempts to download MySQL as 32 and 64 bit in Debian packages and it keeps failing. See below for what i wrote in the terminal. As you can see I get an error. I also get an error in the Ubuntu Software Center stating " Dependency is not satisfiable: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1) ". Could you please give me some guidance so I know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -i '/home/user/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.47-1ubu1204-i386.deb'Selecting previously deselected package mysql-workbench-gpl.
(Reading database ... 118286 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-workbench-gpl (from .../mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.47-1ubu1204-i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-gpl:
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.12.1-0ubuntu6.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libctemplate0; however:
  Package libctemplate0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.26.0-0ubuntu1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.32.0); however:
  Version of libglibmm-2.4-1c2a on system is 2.25.5-0ubuntu1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Version of libgtk2.0-0 on system is 2.22.0-0ubuntu1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Version of libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a on system is 1:2.20.3-1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1); however:
  Package libmysqlclient18 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Version of libpangomm-1.4-1 on system is 2.26.2-1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libpcre3 (>= 8.10); however:
  Version of libpcre3 on system is 8.02-1.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libpython2.7 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.5.1-7ubuntu2.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on libzip2 (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libzip2 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on python-paramiko; however:
  Package python-paramiko is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on mysql-client; however:
  Package mysql-client is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-gpl depends on python-pysqlite2; however:
  Package python-pysqlite2 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-workbench-gpl (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-gpl
```

Comment: 10.10? NO he did not... he should know 10.10 is end of life. Use 12.04 and mysql+workbench will install :+ Beside that for future installing: when using DPKG you must manually install all the dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Open your terminal. Write the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libctemplate0 libzip1 python-pysqlite2 mysql-client python-crypto python-paramiko
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Press Enter and write down your password then another Enter. Done

Comment: @Rinzwind I edited the answer

Comment: When i Open the terminal and type in the command i get this...

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench
user@ubuntu:~$

Comment: @user247553 what do you get?

Comment: @kamil he's on 10.10.  That will error with getting dependencies.

Comment: @user247553 I advise you to install ubuntu 12.04 at least because it's a long term stable release and still supported by mysql workbench. any way try my answer edited above

Comment: @ThomasW. actually there is no mysql official release right now to 10.10. Although 10.04 have a download in their site. I am trying to help

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
user@ubuntu:~$

Comment: @user247553 that's not a problem. continue

Comment: @kamil That's not what I meant.  I meant the dependencies don't exist on the mirrors anymore.  10.10 is EOL which means it is no longer supported.  The user needs to use a non-End of Life release.

Comment: For the second command line you suggested I get this...

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libctemplate0 libzip1 python-pysqlite2 mysql-client python-crypto python-paramiko
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libctemplate0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libzip1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source...
etc

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench
user@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I advise you as moderators are saying to upgrade at least to version 12.04 because you cannot solve this problem easily.

Answer (score 4):

You want to install MySQL Workbench.

The version you try to install is made for Ubuntu 12.04 and has some versions requirements for some of the deps.

You need to try with MySQL Workbench for 10.04/10.10 if you are forced to use 10.10, but still it would be recommended to use 12.04.

Also, after you will install MySQL Workbench compatible with 10.10, you will need to do

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix dependencies.

If you downloaded from MySQL.com, then choose older versions (on the right side of Select Platform) and download 10.04 version. Choose 32 if your installation is on 32 or 64 in case of 64.

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu Linux 10.04 (x86, 32-bit), DEB and the I get the same error. Is there something else that could be preventing me from installing MySQL? This is what I got when i entered the command you suggested above...is this what is suppose to happen?

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
user@ubuntu:~$

Comment: try to clean any changes previous done.

`sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench-gpl`

no retry with the recent download and run

`sudo apt-get install -f`

to get all those deps.